# Optional values in SPARQL use in javascript

Tags: javascript, sparql, semantic-web

I use data from a SPARQL query in my JavaScript. 
This is my query:

```
PREFIX ns1: <http://example.org/project/> 
SELECT ?state ?university ?city ?athletes ?motto 
WHERE 
{ 
?university a ns1:universitiess ; 
            ns1:is_in_city ?city .  
?state ns1:has_University ?university . 
OPTIONAL {?university ns1:has_athleticsProgram ?athletes .} 
OPTIONAL {?university ns1:has_moto ?motto .}
}
```

I use this javascript code

```
angular.forEach(data.results.bindings, function(val)
     {

         let jsonData = {
           state: val.state.value,
           university: val.university.value,
           city: val.city.value,

           // athletes: val.athletes.value,
           // motto: val.motto.value
         }
         $scope.myDynamicData.push(jsonData);


     })
```

But this won't work with the `OPTIONAL` ones from my query: so `athletes` and `motto`. Does anyone know how i can use the data for the ones that `motto`/`athletes` exists?

Comment: It's literally the same question as before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547742/use-value-on-new-page-sparql-html - Vote to close!

Comment: and it remains totally unclear what your problem is. You never said if you get an error or whatever.

Comment: Looks like you might want to assemble some conditional assignments into the `jsonData` assignment?